# Get cookie from another website with cUrl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

How can I get cookie from another website with cUrl?

I want to get cookie of this https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-ae/niv/users/sign_in site!

For example:

```
Cookie:
_ga=GA1.2.1101352908.1469077182; _yatri_session=TTNTOWhoQjJoTHVNNkVnQ29XOGxqVUZxQzJXYWpBZjhOQWhaSFVnQlhqUDhSLytCelA2K2UvSEl1TG1MUmRDL2JUNi95b1pRa2pJVGpGdmxGWmh6dWI0ckppOVVoUnNObWJjLyt0MFF2bmppeGJLNEVxNFdaODBQQWhPb3VrSlh3bTJoWGVpTFdwSTJxRFpPNVRSeTBlZHg3bWR1WnVKZk0rMWRCeHYxSnFESG5EVVJlRnRJbytGZUl4SzAzYjdkWnoySFcySkt1MW53UlpJU21mcGpROHppVHdJblJmWDB4clFTTHRtR1BtM29lVUtqMWtBaERLeVp5d094SFBhYldyR1NvTHR5dFBGMDdCYVlhcWdiM0ttSzFCRWxpNHZMaktKMEpGd01Ub0p3enpVZFVLSDBrb2VhdmNTWDJOazJ0MkFCemVpci85aWZKS1JPczhiaml2eEQ1YTYzZVUzcDJ5K2dRYUk2dnAxUnNTTk5yMkpaY2VOVWJCRUM5bERlLS1ITFFaK05wNWFmaDhUOTZlYVhlbk5RPT0%3D--dc9cf7a71467b9d93e656e087ccf4a3841304cb5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code:

```
<?php
    // open a site with cookies
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-ae/niv/users/sign_in");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER  ,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    // get cookies
    $cookies = array();
    preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie:(?<cookie>\s{0,}.*)$/im', $content, $cookies);

    echo $cookies['cookie'][0];

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What should I do if I just value to be displayed? I do not want to be in the array, because I want to post the cookie to the Web site with cURL.

Comment: Edited my answer, this will print the value you want.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. About this post can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940353/login-to-website-with-curl-and-deathbycaptcha-php

Comment: Why should the OP "check the code below"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.